# Generating a Favicon only with code // no image

Tags: favicon

Is there a way to generate a Square Favicon 1solid color via code instead of uploading a png or ico file? by Only specifying the color code?

HTML or JS or other?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends what kind of web server you're using. With Twisted, for instance, you could generate the response for the favicon URL using code.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) for favicons says they have to be files located at a fixed location. I guess it depends on what you consider "uploading" to be. Would having a server-side PHP script generate a file on your server be acceptable?